# How can I Format an Oracle SQL query in a way that the output makes a 'Create Table Statement'?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Ok, so I'm trying to create a batch file that runs a 'Compile' Oracle SQL File. The 'Compile' file will have 2 procedures, one of which will extract tables from my schema and the other one will extract the columns within that table. I will then run another Oracle SQL file from my batch file (called 'RUN') which will run the procedures and create an output file of type Oracle SQL. This output SQL file must be properly formated because it is a report. I have created the batch file, and i have also created the 2 procedures that display the tables and columns. But so far I'm having no luck in creating the the 'RUN' file in a way that the output matches the image provided.[The Output SQL file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzBiV.png)

Here is the Code for the 2 Procedures in the Compile File

```
DROP PROCEDURE Extract_Columns;

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Extract_Tables
AS
BEGIN
    
    FOR CurrentRow IN(
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM USER_TABLES)
    LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CurrentRow.table_name || ', ' );
    extract_columns(CurrentRow.table_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
Show ERRORS;

EXEC extract_tables;

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Extract_Columns(
    iTable IN USER_TABLES.table_name%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
    
    FOR CurrentRow IN ( SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = iTable)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CurrentRow.Column_Name || ', ' );
        END LOOP;
END;
/

EXEC extract_columns;
```

And here is the output of the above procedures

```
CUSTOMERS, 
CUSTNUM, 
COMPANY, 
CUSTREP, 
CREDITLIMIT, 
SALESREPS, 
SALESREP, 
NAME, 
AGE, 
REPOFFICE, 
TITLE, 
HIREDATE, 
MANAGER, 
QUOTA, 
SALES, 
OFFICES, 
OFFICE, 
CITY, 
REGION, 
MGR, 
TARGET, 
SALES, 
ORDERS, 
ORDERNUM, 
ORDERDATE, 
CUST, 
REP, 
MFR, 
PRODUCT, 
QTY, 
AMOUNT, 
PRODUCTS, 
MFR, 
PRODUCT, 
DESCRIPTION, 
PRICE, 
QTYONHAND,
```

Customers, Offices, Orders, Products, Salesreps from the above outuput are the tables and the rows following each of them are their respective columns. All I want is to take the above output and transform it into the picture given. How should I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

As of **Oracle**: I presume you don't really plan to run the resulting "script" anywhere because it won't work; you know that, right? There are no datatypes, precisions, scales, sizes, constraints ... If you wanted *that*, investigate `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`.

As of your script: see if this helps; I'm extracting only two tables (just for example) and their columns.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_crt varchar2(32000);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_t in (select table_name
  5                  from user_tables
  6                  where table_name in ('EMP', 'DEPT')
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      l_crt := 'create table ' || cur_t.table_name ||' (';
 10
 11      for cur_c in (select c.column_name
 12                    from user_tab_columns c
 13                    where c.table_name = cur_t.table_name
 14                    order by c.column_id
 15                   )
 16      loop
 17        l_crt := l_crt || chr(10) || cur_c.column_name ||',';
 18      end loop;
 19
 20        l_crt := rtrim(l_crt, ',') || ');';
 21        dbms_output.put_line(l_crt || chr(10) || '--' );
 22        l_crt := null;
 23    end loop;
 24  end;
 25  /
create table DEPT (
DEPTNO,
DNAME,
LOC);
--
create table EMP (
EMPNO,
ENAME,
JOB,
MGR,
HIREDATE,
SAL,
COMM,
DEPTNO);
--

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```